# Write an array of differing lengths to a csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a large number of fields from a Class to a csv. E.g.

```
for i in range(0,  len(t)):
    t.writerow([t[i].a,  t[i].b,  t[i].c,...]
```

However I have a subclass which I also want to write at the end of this list:

```
for i in range(0,  len(t)):
    t.writerow([  t[i].a,  t[i].b,  t[i].c,...  t[i].z[0].s,  t[i].z[1].s ...])
```

However I'm not sure how I achieve this, the subclasses are of varying lengths, so how would I ensure that each row just appends the relevant number of subclasses at the end? I can't find anything in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) about it. Do I make a string out of the subclass entries, and then just paste one entry at the end? Thanks.

Comment: It's very hard to read your sample code, please add some whitespace to make it more obvious where the things begin and end. Oh, and three dots `...` is sufficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think writing it something like this would work:

```
for i in range(len(t)):
    row = [[ e.a, e.b, e.c, ...] + [e.z[0], e.z[1], e.z[2], ...] for e in t[i]]
    t.writerow(row)
```

Comment: thanks, I had gone and made an empty list and appended with a for loop , but that looks a lot nicer!

Answer (score 1):

If `z` is just a python `list`, just append it to the list of fields from `t`:

```
t.writerow([t[i].a, t[i].b, t[i].c, ...] + t[i].z)
```

which would be the same as `[one, list] + [another, list]`.

It looks like you can just loop over `t` (a list) itself instead of using a `range()`:

```
for item in t:
    t.writerow([item.a, item.b, item.c, ...] + item.z)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. It's not quite a list. It's a subclass as in t.z[1].s, t.z[2].s.... I tried what you suggested but that didn't work. That was my fault, I've edited the OP

Comment: I could make t.z.s into a list though and then add it?